# php domdocument get node info

Tags: php, domdocument

I am working with php and I am trying to get certain data from a webpage

everything works till i get to this part:

```
<a class="cleanthis" href="https://www.web.com" id="1122" rel="#1122" style="display: inline-block;"><strong>the data i want</strong></a>
```

As you can see i want the data in strong but i cant get it. I only get blank lines

code i use:

```
foreach($as as $a) {
        if ($a->getAttribute('class') === 'cleanthis') {


$strong =  $a->getElementsByTagName('strong');
echo $strong->nodeValue;;

}
```

Comment: Maybe it’s a typo from simplifying it, but the class is `cleanthis` and you’re looking for `hoverinfo_trigger`

Comment: I've made a typo, sorry

Comment: I would use the style to make the text strong.. not in favour of styles mixed with markup. then you can select the element by ID for instance..

Comment: I can't change that, this is from an other website so i cant do anything about is.

Answer (score 0):

You should be seeing this error message:

> Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$nodeValue

That is because `$strong = $a->getElementsByTagName('strong');` will put a `DOMNodeList` in `$string`. You either need to iterate the list or retrieve the actual node from it, e.g.

```
echo $strong->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Or you can just use XPath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//a[@class="cleanthis"]/strong/text()') as $element) {
    echo $element->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I must use the domdocument way and that still did not work